# CSS Grid container not centered to the browser viewport

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have defined a CSS grid with the below properties. However, I am finding that the entire grid container is not centered (vertically & horizontally) to my browser window on my Chrome desktop browser (Macbook Pro 15" Display).

Can someone help me as to how to center the entire grid container to the middle of the browser viewport?

```
html { 

    background: url('images/cbg.png') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover; /* Safari */
    -moz-background-size: cover; /* Mozilla Firefox */
    -o-background-size: cover; /* Opera Browser */
    background-size: cover; /* Chrome */


    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    text-align: center;
    }

body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: 20px;

    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-items: center; 
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;

  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr); 
   /* grid-template-columns: 1fr; */
  grid-gap: 5px;

}
```

/**** Updated with Grid Items that go into the CSS grid container .wrapper ****/

```
.box {
  background-color: #444;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-size: 150%;
}

.box-txt {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.header1
    {

        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 12;
        grid-row-start: 2;
        grid-row-end: 3; 
        text-align: center;
        height: 80px;
        background: rgb(2,0,36);
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(203,203,227,1) 100%, rgba(255,211,0,1) 100%);
    }

.footer{
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 12;
        grid-row-start: 5;
        grid-row-end: 6;
        text-align: center;
        height: 120px;
        background: rgb(2,0,36);
        background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(203,203,227,1) 100%, rgba(255,211,0,1) 100%);
    }

.imgbox {
        grid-column-start: 6;
        grid-column-end: 12;
        grid-row-start: 3;
        grid-row-end: 4;
        height: 500px;
    }

    .imgbox > img {
        width: 100%;
        height:100%;
        display: block;
        object-fit: cover;
        border-radius: 5px;
        }

    .b {
        grid-column-start: 2;
        grid-column-end: 3;
        grid-row-start: 2;
        grid-row-end: 3;
    }
    .c {
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 6;
        grid-row-start: 3;
        grid-row-end: 4;
    }
    .d {
        grid-column-start: 7;
        grid-column-end: 12; 
        grid-row-start: 4;
        grid-row-end: 5;
    }
```

Comment: You are setting the alignment properties against the `body` element. Move them to the `.wrapper` element. https://jsfiddle.net/57bd4w6m/

Comment: Have you tried to put a `margin:auto` to your .wrapper ? Or maybe with a `display:flex` on your body. It's hard to help without the associated html

Comment: @Morpheus I tried the changes suggested by you to the .wrapper but my entire grid fell apart with those settings. Please remember that I am using several grid-items defined with grid-lines. I am updating my question to add more details about my grid contents.

Comment: @mdubus I tried both (display:flex on body and margin:auto ). Both did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need :

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 20px;
    width:100%;
    height: 100vh;

    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;

  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr); 
   /* grid-template-columns: 1fr; */
  grid-gap: 5px;

}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="col-1">1</div>
    <div class="col-1">2</div>
    <div class="col-1">3</div>
    <div class="col-1">4</div>
    <div class="col-1">5</div>
    <div class="col-1">6</div>
    <div class="col-1">7</div>
    <div class="col-1">8</div>
    <div class="col-1">9</div>
    <div class="col-1">10</div>
    <div class="col-1">11</div>
    <div class="col-1">12</div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Let me know if you need more help :)

Comment: That did not work. Please check my updated code with the grid items that go into the CSS grid container.

Comment: I updated my code to what I guess is your expectation. 
If it's not what you want, can you please also provide your HTML as well ?

Answer (score -2):

Try using flex in that place.

To the wrapper you can add

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

Hope this works

Comment: `justtify-contents` is not a property. Please check for errors before posting. It should be `justify-content`

Comment: My entire page is already coded on the css grid properties and I cannot switch to a display:flex now. I need to center my existing css grid container .wrapper itself to the viewport.